# How to fix "You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/gb2/gbrowse/yeast on this server."

Tags: apache, cgi, bioinformatics, cgi-bin

I tried to install gbrowse2 at  ubuntu 15:04. when the installation went smoothly, but when I call link display an error message

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/gb2/gbrowse/yeast on this
>   server. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.88.25.48 Port 80

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing the permissions as

```
sudo chmod 755 +R /cgi-bin/gb2/gbrowse/
```

Answer (score 0):

These changes resolved permission issue and executed cgi file as excepted.

Apache 2.2:

```
LoadModule cgid_module /mod_cgid.so
LoadModule cgi_module /mod_cgi.so

<IfModule alias_module>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "local/scratch/apache/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

 <Directory "/pathtocgifolder/cgi-bin/">
   AllowOverride none
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Options +ExecCGI
<Directory>
```